# NSLog only shows from main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c

My phone is iOS 10.1 and xcode is 8.1.

I build and test the iOS App through terminal. I used xcodebuild xctestrun from terminal to run my unit test.

```
xcodebuild  -xctestrun {} -destination '{}' -derivedDataPath '{}' test-without-building"
```

In my unit test, I need to spawn the another thread and I need to log information from this thread.  However, I could not see any logging information from this thread (not main thread). I even can not see the type of exception I raised from the this thread (not main thread).

When I raise an exception not in the main thread

```
- (void)test1 {
    // We always run the test in another thread because we need the main thread to spin for the UI.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [NSException raise:@"ContentSyncException"
                    format:@"Timeout out waiting for %lu content", self.contentCount];
    });
}
```

I got

```
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

However if I raise the same NSException in the main thread

```
- (void)test1 {    
     [NSException raise:@"ContentSyncException"
                    format:@"Timeout out waiting for %lu content", self.contentCount];

    // We always run the test in another thread because we need the main thread to spin for the UI.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    });
}
```

I got

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ContentSyncException', reason: 'Timeout out waiting for 3 content currently 0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186cf21b4 0x18572c55c 0x186cf20fc 0x1012c2070 0x1012c3464 0x185b7d1fc 0x185b7d1bc 0x185b8ba4c 0x185b8d34c 0x185b8d0ac 0x185d862a0 0x185d85d8c)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks in advance